# const qualifier disappears from pure virtual function

Tags: c++, constants, pure-virtual

Using gcc version 4.8.2:

I'm running into an issue where the const qualifier on my parameters is disappearing when I compile my code. Here is an example:

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
        public:
        virtual int getSum( const int number ) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
        public:
        Derived( const int& num )
        : _myNumber( num )
        {}

        virtual int getSum( const int number )
        {
                return _myNumber + number;
        }

        private:
        int _myNumber;
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
        Base *b = new Derived( 2 );

        std::cout << b->getSum( 3 ) << "\n";

}
```

Compiled like so:

```
g++ main.cc -o const_test
```

When I run nm:

```
nm const_test | c++filt | grep getSum
```

I get the following output:

```
0000000000400b60 W Derived::getSum(int)
```

Why does the const disappear from my function when it compiles?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ More precisely, it *has* a meaning (inside the function) but it’s not part of the signature.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Write that up as an answer.

Comment: It is a language rule, cv-qualifiers on function arguments are ignored for overload resolution.  Section 13.1 of the C++ language spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function signature

```
virtual int getSum(const int number) = 0;
```

is actually exactly equivalent to

```
virtual int getSum(int number) = 0;
```

`const` has no effect on the function signature declaration for parameters passed by value.

The only effect is, that you can't change the parameter instance on the stack inside of a potential definition of this method. It's in fact sufficient to put it only there, to prevent changing the parameter's instance in the function body.

Comment: It might be worth adding that what matters is the signature in the function definition. You mentioned the two signatures are identical, but sometimes people don't understand the implications of this.

Comment: @juanchopanza THX for pointing out, I tried to clarify this a bit.