# Virtual functions with varying of function parameters in derived class by const type in "function parameter" will break virtual mechanism?

Tags: c++, inheritance

A C++ guru told that varying the function parameter type with const in derived class, will break the virtual call mechanism.

I tried a simple program ( forgive for non standard code, written purely for test) , which prove otherwise.
The function parameter change by const value will not break the virtual mechanism,

Is there any reasons & documentation pointing to this behavior?

Behavior noted with  VS 2012 compiler & latest g++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Base
{
public:
Base(){ cout<<"base"<<endl;}
virtual ~Base(){ cout<<"dest base"<<endl;}
virtual void test(const int x){ cout << "base test"<<"x = " << x<<endl;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
Derived(){ cout<<"derived"<<endl;}
virtual ~Derived(){ cout<<"dest derived"<<endl;}
virtual void test(int x){ cout << "derived test"<<"x = " << x<<endl;}
};
int main() {

    Base *b = new Derived();
    b->test(10);
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
base
derived
derived testx = 10
dest derived
dest base
```

Comment: Your guru was probable talking about something like `foo(int&)` vs `foo(const int&)`.

Comment: Beware that, in general, code that demonstrates a behavior is not proof of that behavior. For example, I could construct an example on my platform that uses a dangling reference to an `int` and that would appear to work. But that isn't proof that it works in general, only that I was (un)lucky with my undefined behavior. Because of the existence of undefined behavior, showing that something behaves in a certain way doesn't prove that it will always behave that way. It's best to instead rely on credible documentation, ideally the standard itself.

Comment: likely dupe of [Top-level const doesn't influence a function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208570/top-level-const-doesnt-influence-a-function-signature) or [Why does a function declaration with a const argument allow calling of a function with a non-const argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681188/why-does-a-function-declaration-with-a-const-argument-allow-calling-of-a-functio); see also the more searchable [const qualifier disappears from pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290732/const-qualifier-disappears-from-pure-virtual-function)

Comment: It doesn't "break" anything; it's simply that an overriding function must have the same argument list as the function that it overrides. Just as `void f(int)` in a derived class doesn't override `virtual void f(double)` in a base class, `void f(int&)` doesn't override `virtual void(const int&)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top level cv-qualifier is not part of function signature, they are simply ignored.

[[dcl.fct]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#5)

> After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type.

Answer (score 4):

Your `C++ guru` is wrong (provided you understood them, gurus tend to talk in cryptic messages). `Const`-qualifier on the argument type itself is not a part of a function signature at all.

For example, `void foo(int* const );` is no different from `void foo(int* )`. Please note, it is not the same as const qualification of the indirect object, like `void foo(const int* )` is different from `void foo(int* )`.

In your particular case, `void test(int x)` is the same as `void test(int const x)`

Answer (score 4):

`void test(int)` != `void test(int) const` and would "break" virtual call.
and `void test(int&)` != `void test(const int&)` and would "break" virtual call.

`void test(int)` is the same declaration than `void test(const int)` and won't "break" virtual call.

Comment: everything right. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of std::decay happens to argument types for functions.  (It's actually the reverse, std::decay is modeled after what functions arguments do.)

The *outermost* const will be dropped from the signature.  By outermost, think of types as envelopes composed over different types.  A pointer to const int is a different type than a pointer to int, and will result in a different function signature.  (With a pointer, you can think of the pointer itself as the outer thing, and what it points to is "inner" and not modified.)

- *`const int`* - becomes just *`int`*
- *`int *`* is unchanged and remains *`int *`*
- *`const int *`* is unchanged and remains *`const int *`* - const is on the int, not the pointer, and only the outermost const is dropped
- *`int const *`* is unchanged and remains *`int const *`* - const is on the int, not the pointer, and only the outermost const is dropped.  (Note, this is 100% identical in meaning as `const int *`)
- *`int * const`* - changes to *`int *`* - because const qualifies the outermost pointer
- *`int * const * const`* becomes *`int * const *`* - outer const is dropped on outer pointer, inner const is not dropped on the inner pointer.
- *`const int * const * const`* becomes *`const int * const *`* - outer const is dropped on outer pointer, inner const is not dropped on the inner pointer, and const is also kept on the internal-most int
- *`MyTemplate<const T>`* - unchanged, remains *`MyTemplate<const T>`*, because the const isn't on the outer type, but nestled in a template parameter

So yes, const does affect type, but not in the simple case like you tried.  Only when it's contained inside of a type, not affecting the outermost type.

If you read types from *right-to-left* it can help.  If the rightmost thing in a type specifier is a *const*, it is always dropped (example `int * const`).  If the leftmost thing is const, it is only dropped if the thing it is qualifying is the rightmost thing in the type (example `const int`, the leftmost thing is const and it affects the int to its right AND the int to its right is the rightmost thing in the type.)  (example 2: `const * int` not dropped, because leftmost const modifies the thing to its right that is not the rightmost thing in the type.)

Comment: This is a good perspective on it. Also: This is why I strictly enforce right-to-left types in all my own code! `int const *const` it has to be.

Comment: When I get to decide the coding style, that's my rule too.  Yes, the rule for const is to modify the thing to its left _unless_ there is nothing to its left, in which case it does the thing to its right.  Modifying the thing to its right is the _exception_ to the rule, and makes reading out loud right-to-left more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

He was right.just found it by seeing the warning.

In this case : Compilers before VS2008 would break the virtual mechanism in this case.

Later compilers it gives warning C4373: virtual function overrides '%$pS', previous versions of the compiler did not override when parameters only differed by const/volatile qualifiers

found the documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384874.aspx

Comment: _"He was right"_ does not follow from _'one compiler was buggy at one point in time'_ (and now emits a rather spurious warning). This is a useful factoid, for sure. However, it's not an answer. A "C++ guru" would refer to the Standard, not one version of one compiler.

Comment: @underscore_d if this compiler is actually used in this setting, than of course guru is right, but the OP is wrong omitting this detail.

Comment: Added up there, thanks for giving loads of good answers!

Comment: Writing portable code, you still have to think about versions?

Comment: It's not _right_ if it's an untrue statement--even if it happened to function as expected in one specific, broken context.  At best, it's just not "100% wrong in all situations."